# What is a possible cause for [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] in Python Requests library?

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, python-requests

The following example GET:

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=(self.key, ''), verify=False)
```

Fails with the following traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)

requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Running python 2.7.12

I can confirm this IS NOT a duplicate of [Python requests gives SSL unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099208/python-requests-gives-ssl-unknown-protocol)

- Question 32099208 is specific to a port issue on the requested URL
- My target URL works as expected in clients other than Python Requests

  - https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/test/v1/employees/directory

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate of a question which deals with the same topic. If you don't feel that this other question helps you please provide the URL in  question so that one can have a closer look and reproduce the problem. In general you get this error if the other side does not reply with TLS, which can have multiple reasons (messed setup, middleboxes like firewalls, old server with SSL 2.0 ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem turned out to be related to the requests library.

Adding the following to my python library resolved the issue:

`pip install requests[security]`

(Note this is not an ideal fix for TLS future security)